When opening AndroidManifest.xml there were several errors and I didn't find a solution for them


I had gradle errors and fixed them, but when I run the application, it opens and closes immediately and the phone sends me a message  Something went wrong with mk mk closed because this app has a bug.
Try updating this app after its developer provides a fix for this error.
Got it

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Those warnings are from the native android building system (specially Android Studio). I am using vs code.
If you want to resolve it go through the suggestions provided in the terminal and try to fix it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
